# Grouped boxplot combined with dotplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to stackoverflow so please be forgiving, if the way of asking my question can be improved (in that case I'm happy if you let me know how).

I am using the following code in ggplot2 to produce a grouped boxplot combined with a dotplot (unfortunately I cannot post an image yet (no reputation)):

```
ggplot(data24, aes(x=intensity, y=percacc, fill=group)) +
       geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(1), notch=T,
                    outlier.colour = NA, width = .7, alpha=0.2) +
       geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", binwidth = 3,
                    position=position_dodge(1), dotsize=0.5, alpha=1) +
       stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=5,
                    position=position_dodge(0.3)) +
       stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.1, 
                    position=position_dodge(0.3), size=1.2)+
       scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100)) +
       scale_fill_discrete(name="Group")
```

My questions are:

- How can use different colors for different elements? I tried to add color/fill commands within geom_boxplot() and geom_dotplot, but this doesn't work: e.g., if I add fill="green" to geom_dotplot(), all points become green and centered between the boxplots. How can I rewrite the code to get
- white fill for all boxplots
- blue fill and black line for dots of group 1
- green fill and black line for dots of group 2
- black fill for all mean diamonds

  2. How can pull the categories of "intensity" (i.e. the three pairs of boxplots) further apart from each other?
  3. How can I display the dotplots next to the boxplots and the mean+CI in the boxplot?
  4. Why does my coordination system still go from <0 to >100, even if I defined the y-axis to go from 0 to 100?

Thank you!

Edit 180722

Thank you for your comments. The data head is:

```
   id intensity AQ_sum group acc   percacc
1  54        40     11  COMP   5  20.83333
2  54        60     11  COMP  18  75.00000
3  54        80     11  COMP  24 100.00000
4  55        40     12  COMP   9  37.50000
5  55        60     12  COMP  22  91.66667
6  55        80     12  COMP  24 100.00000
7  58        40     10  COMP   8  33.33333
8  58        60     10  COMP  22  91.66667
9  58        80     10  COMP  23  95.83333
10 59        40      6  COMP  19  79.16667
11 59        60      6  COMP  24 100.00000
12 59        80      6  COMP  24 100.00000
13 60        40      9  COMP  10  41.66667
14 60        60      9  COMP  23  95.83333
15 60        80      9  COMP  22  91.66667
16 61        40     13  COMP   4  16.66667
17 61        60     13  COMP  19  79.16667
18 61        80     13  COMP  24 100.00000
19 62        40     12  COMP  16  66.66667
20 62        60     12  COMP  23  95.83333
```

My updated code is

```
ggplot(data24, aes(x=intensity, y=percacc, fill=group)) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(0.8), notch=T,
               outlier.colour = NA, width = .4, alpha=0.3) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", binwidth = 3,
               position=position_dodge(0.8), dotsize=0.4, alpha=1)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00"), name="Group") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=3,
               position=position_dodge(0.2)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.1, 
               position=position_dodge(0.2), size=0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,103), expand = c(0, 0), 
                     breaks=c(0,20,40,60,80,100), name="Percentage accuracy") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0.6), name="Degree of intensity (in percent)") +
  labs(title="Accuracy by intensity and group\n") +
  theme_light()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face='bold', size=12, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=10,hjust=0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=10,vjust=1),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=10,color='black'),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=10, color='black'),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = 0.3, linetype = "dotted", color="darkgrey"), 
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(size = 0.3, linetype = "dotted", color="darkgrey"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour = "black")) +
  ggsave("plotintensity.png", width = 10, height = 5)
```

[image: See image of the graph]

Comment: Hi Lisa. Your question is too broad and you didn't provided any example of your data. Check this [quick guide on boxplots in STHDA](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-box-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization), it will be easy for you to understand why you not getting color/fill by group the way you want. As for the y-axis range, by default ggplot expand the limits of the axis for a better visualization. Add `expand = c(0,0)` inside scale_y_continuous() to change that.

Comment: Where can we find the dataset `data24`? In what package? If we can't, please post the output of `dput(head(data24, 30))` in the question.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta Thank you for the tip on the axis-range. I still couldn't figure out how I can plot the each dotplot on the left side of its boxplot, and the mean+CI within the boxplot. Do you have any advice on that?